# Editing permission levels for SharePoint SPFx app

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, spfx, spfx-webparts, groups

I asked a similar question a few days ago and got a very good response on how to get started.

I have a SharePoint site using a SPFx react app that I created. The app is contains a sophisticated form for contractors to fill out. When the contractor fills out the form and hits submit, it adds an item to the list using a snippet like this:

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Contracts").items.add({
    //pushing items to a the contracts list
}));
```

I created a new role called `contractors`, I do not want them to be able to view any other list, be able to click on `site contents` and check data on the site, or if it's possible be able to view the list, because it will contain other people's information. I think the best way would be to somehow hide the toolbar for this role.

Here is a link to a screenshot of my current edit permission level, currently the way it's set up I'm getting a `Error making HttpClient request in queryable: [403]` . When I select all or give more access it works, I'm trying to give them the most basic access while allowing them to add/edit item on the list.

Here is the screenshot: https://ibb.co/y5Z4rwJ

Comment: This is clear as mud. Who is getting the error? When is the error happening? Is it a user in the Contractors group that gets it? Where is the error being displayed?

Comment: @jpollar the user is in a contractors group correct. He get's this error as soon as he submits the form. When submitting the form it sends a request to add an item to a list. This error is found in inspect console

Comment: are you getting a line number telling you exactly where the code fails?

Comment: are users in the Contractors group able to add items to the list directly within SharePoint without getting the 403?

Answer (score 0):

As per the permission level screenshot provided by you https://ibb.co/y5Z4rwJ, the "Use Remote Interfaces" permission is not selected which is required for rest services. Please select "Use Remote Interfaces" permission level and then check if the functionality works fine

**Reference:**
[Permissions check box "Use Remote Interfaces" when unchecked prevents users from accessing site. why?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/249415/permissions-check-box-use-remote-interfaces-when-unchecked-prevents-users-from)